# How to Rescue ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid Error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, activerecord

Does anyone know how to rescue this ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid error in rails? The console displays "PG::InvalidTextRepresentation: ERROR: invalid input syntax for integer...". I've tried inserting a pry into the rescue block, but it's never called.

```
  if (resource_params[:term].present?)
    begin
      key = resource_params[:term]
      scope = scope.where("id = ? OR item_type = ? OR item_id = ? OR event = ? OR object ILIKE ?", key, key, key, key, "%#{key}%") 
    rescue
      # handle error 
    end 
  end
```

Please note that I know how to prevent the error from occurring (i.e. need to convert the key to type integer for the id columns). But, I'm trying to understand why it never reaches the rescue block.

UPDATE: my initial post contained a syntax error (namely: rescue e => error) as others correctly pointed out. i'm still receiving the same error without the syntax error; i've update the code to remove the incorrect syntax.

Comment: `rescue e => error` should just be `rescue ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid => error`

Comment: @lgants did you ever figure out what was wrong here?

Answer (score 5):

This isn't the correct syntax for rescue:

```
rescue e => error
```

if I try and use this I get `undefined local variable or method 'e'`

The standard way to rescue a specific error class is to use:

```
rescue ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid => e
```

To do a "naked rescue" (which is often advised against), leave out the class name:

```
rescue => e
```

Note that in all these cases the `=> e` can be left out if you don't need a variable pointing to the error object.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply max-pleaner. I've tried a rescue with ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid as well as a naked rescue, but the execution continues without hitting the rescue block.

Comment: Changte it to a naked rescue, then `puts e.class` inside the rescue block. That is the class you need to rescue. You can also inspect `e.message` and `e.backtrace`.

Comment: That's a cool trick; hadn't thought of that. But, unfortunately it's still not hitting the rescue. I placed a pry immediately beneath the where query in the begin block, but it didn't hit that either. So, it seems the error is causing execution to stop.

Comment: try `rescue Exception => e` ... there are different "exception levels". The naked rescue handles StandardError and below in the exception hierarchy. Rescuing `Exception` should handle the rest of the errors

Answer (score 0):

`rescue ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid => e` is the right syntax and should work fine, but also keep in mind that exception should actually be raised within that block.

rails executes a query when we actually try using its output(for example rendering page where we are displaying output of a query).